# Pasting value using jquery into .NET Textbox is showing the value but not saving

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, textbox, code-behind

I am pasting the value in the .NET Textbox WebApplication (WebForm) using the javascript, and the value is also appearing in the textbox on the webpage upon pasting.

Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" Text="" runat="server"/>

document.getElementById('txtFullName').value = "John Smith";
```

**Pasting:** I am accessing the Textbox from the webpage using the ID of the textbox and assigning the value using the ".value" of the control.

But when I am saving the value, the value isn't there in the textbox.

Value isn't appearing while accessing the control in the codebehind file of the webpage.

Comment: Open the browser dev tools and observe the network POST when you're "saving". Is the the value POSTed to the server?

Comment: @Crowcoder: No, the value isn't there in the POST, it's not getting the value.

Comment: is the TextBox inside a Form?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, TextBox is inside the Form.